# ufw rule deny default outgoing

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

I want to deny all outgoing traffic by default, except `ssh` connections.  I added this rules:

```
ufw default deny outgoing
ufw allow ssh
```

Then I restarted the firewall by:

```
ufw disable
ufw enable
```

Should  this do the trick? I also want to deploy a Rails Application on this server. And my *hello-world* Rails App Server is bound to the server ip with a port. I choose 3000. After the setup of the firewall I expected to not be able to reach my Rails app anymore. But it is still there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The solution is that my host provider also offers Plesk. And there is a firewall running which somehow overwrites everything i setup manually.